# Lazy load dynamically loaded (JS) <iframe>

Tags: javascript, iframe, lazy-loading

I have a ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 website, where i generate some iframes with the following (AJAX):

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('iframe01').contentWindow.document.write(data);  
</script
```

I want these to be lazy-loaded. I've found some libs (http://sourcey.com/recliner/), but it requires that i manually set the `data-src` attribute on the iframe. I can't do that, because i load the iframes from some dynamically recieved HTML.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking.  As a note: `document.getElementById('iframe01').contentWindow.document.write(data);` is not ajax. For lazy-loaded you will use  AJAX ( **A**synchronous **J**avaScript **a**nd **X**ML) because with that you can load your content asynchronously on demand.

Comment: I generate some iframes with the script using AJAX...